# installing 'react-router' gives inconsistent version

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4

I installed the react router by doing this :

> npm install react-router

What was installed by me is not consistent with almost all the tutorials I have read on the internet. One example : https://css-tricks.com/learning-react-router/

For a start, it is missing **IndexRoute**. Where is **IndexRoute**? I cannot seem to get any of my examples working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you install a package like

```
npm install react-router
```

It installs the latest package that is available on the npm repository. If you see the package.json, you will have the version the React router to be `4.x.x` which doesn't have IndexRoute

You should install v3.x.x

To do that, remove the entry for react-router from your package.json and delete the `node_modules`.

Now run

```
npm install
```

followed by

```
npm install -S react-router@3.x.x
```

See the **[react-router v4.0.0 Docs](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/core/api/Router)**

Comment: why do the creators have to completely refactor the classes? The first react-router tutorial by using google search "react router tutorial" uses IndexRoute. They should at least keep the classes in and mark them as deprecated... that's half a day gone for me.